# Gemfile not getting created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hi I'm using for some reason Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.12 and RubyGems 1.6.2

I cannot find the Gemfile when i do :

Rails AppName

Almost all the other folders and files are created. Can someone tell me if this is normal for the older version or something is wrong.

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: Were you trying to create a new rails app with `Rails AppName` command?

Comment: I did the rails new appname. But that created the application with new as the name. I guess the old versions of RoR does not need the new keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails 2.3.*` versions did not include bundler by default, as is the case with `rails 3.0` and higher.

See http://bundler.io/v1.3/rails23.html for how to include `bundler` & create a `Gemfile` on your own with `rails 2.3`

Comment: What does request.xhr? mean